# How can I set up Read the Docs so the Sphinx autodoc option works?

Tags: python, git, documentation, mocking, documentation-generation

My project isn't building with autodoc. I'm running into [this frequently asked question about my project not building in autodoc](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc). But, some of dependencies include c code which won't execute on Build the Docs servers. So I read the approach in this [blog explaining that I should use mock](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-make-your-sphinx-documentation-compile-with-readthedocs-when-youre-using-numpy-and-scipy/). This relates to the stackoverflow question 'how-to-mock-so-that-from-x-import-works'.

In the advanced settings section of the admin page on Read the Docs, there's an option to use virtualenv, which I checked, and then the path to the root of my project to requirements.txt is requested.

The project directory is structured as:

```
GatherNews/
    requirements.txt
```

When I use `GatherNews/requirements.txt` as the path. I get the error:

> /var/build/user_builds/gathernews/checkouts/latest/docs/api/grss.rst:10: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class u'CaptureFeeds' from module u'gathernews.gRSS'; the following exception was raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/gathernews/envs/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 335, in import_object **import**(self.modname)
>
> File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/gathernews/envs/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gathernews/**init**.py", line 1, in  import gRSS
>
> File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/gathernews/envs/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gathernews/gRSS.py", line 38, in  import feedparser
>
> ImportError: No module named feedparser /var/build/user_builds/gathernews/checkouts/latest/docs/_themes/README.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree

My question is how do I tie this all together? Specifically, am I using the correct path to my `requirements.txt` for Read the Docs to build successfully? If my path to my `requirements.txt` is correct, then how can I include the mock package to successfully generate autodocs?

Comment: As it stands, this question is very hard to answer, because there is no easy way to test any potential answer. If you could provide a minimalistic skeleton of how your project is set up, and what you've already tried and how it didn't work, it might have a better chance of getting answered.

Comment: I've made additions that I think will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: You could check if the path to your `requirements.txt` is correct like this: Include a dependency on the `requests` module, import it as early as possible in your project (top level `__init__.py`), build docs locally *without* the dependency being satisfied to check that's the first error Sphinx raises, then let RTD build it.

Comment: I've been able to build the docs using sphinx locally & everything looks good. It's just the autodocs issue with Read the Docs. Let me include some more info that will hopefully explain myself better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a fork of https://github.com/Bonza-Times/GatherNews and set of a ReadTheDocs build for it. The only issue seems to be that you used the wrong path to `requirements.txt`. It says

> Path from the root of your project.

so that does not include `GatherNews`. Just use `requirements.txt` as the path, since that file is in the top level of your git repository.

Since you've got `Use virtualenv` checked, ReadTheDocs should automatically take care of making sure the virtualenv's site-packages are available in `sys.path` to the `sphinx-build` script.

I don't see any need for mocking modules, since `feedparser` doesn't have any hard dependencies on C libraries. It *can* be built against libxml2, but it doesn't have to.

With the path to `requirements.txt` fixed I was able to do a successful build.

These are the "Advanced Settings" I used, the remaining settings are at default values:

[image: Advanced settings]